# c++ std::cout in hexadecimal

Tags: c++, hex, output

I have an output statement with `printf` in C++ that looks like this:

```
for(int i=0; i<6; i++)
        printf("%.2X", (unsigned char) iter->hwaddress[i]);
```

I need to do the output with `std::cout`, I have tried to do it like this:

```
for(int i=0; i<6; i++)
   cout << hex << (unsigned char) iter->hwaddress[i];
```

but that just gives me:

```
  �:�:w:�:�:
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to cast it to an `int:

```
char c = 15;
cout << hex << setfill('0') << setw(2) << static_cast<int>(c); // prints "0f"
```

`hex` only affects integer I/O, which `char` isn't considered part of - so your code ends up still outputting the actual `char`s.

Note that if `char` is signed and you need this to work on values larger than `0x7f`, you will have to cast it first to `unsigned char` and then to `unsigned int`:

```
cout << hex << setfill('0') << setw(2)
     << static_cast<unsigned int>(static_cast<unsigned char>(c));
```

Comment: If `char` is signed and `c` is negative, this will give rather longer results than OP expects (and a cast to `unsigned` doesn't help). You'll have to go the awkward-looking route and use `static_cast<unsigned>(static_cast<unsigned char>(c))` to avoid sign-extension.

Answer (score 1):

If the values of those `iter->hwaddress[i]` are hardware addresses, why don't you (reinterpret_)cast them to actual pointers? Then `cout` will print them in hex without any additional effort.

```
cout << reinterpret_cast<void*>(iter->hwaddress[i]);
```

It is not clear if you need fixed number of digits. This may require some tools in `<iomanip>`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't cast to `unsigned char` but to an integer.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdio>

int
main()
{
  char numbers[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
  // Using C-style printf:    
  for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    std::printf("%02X", static_cast<unsigned>(numbers[i]));
  printf("\n");
  // Using C++ streams:
  for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    std::cout << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0')
              << static_cast<unsigned>(numbers[i]);
  std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

The `<<` operator is overloaded on these types.  Also avoid C-style casts in favor of `static_cast` if you need to cast at all.